# Поиск в массиве

Tags: поиск, массивы, php

Есть в наличии одномерный массив формата

```
array('abc','bbf','thf') \\ Массив может иметь несколько миллионов записей
```

Как лучше проводить поиск ключа (и полного значения) по массиву если известна часть значения? 
Ищу аналог `SQL'`ной команды `LIKE %%`.

Comment: Может так:

    $input = preg_quote('bl', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
    $data = array('orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'pink', 'brown', 'black');

    $result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $data);

[думаю это поможет][1]

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808923/filter-values-from-an-array-similar-to-sql-like-search-using-php

Comment: Хорошее решение. А сколько ресурсов скушает preg_grep ?